# Why do i get this error when running "sudo apt install -y mongodb" in terminal

Tags: linux, mongodb, terminal, terminal-services

I am trying to install mongodb on my pop os linux.

I ran this:

```
sudo apt install -y mongodb
```

Then it said this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

How do i fix it? Is there a way to?

Comment: Assuming you're using Ubuntu you'll have to enable the universe repo...

Comment: Yea i just did that and it worked! Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Ubuntu you'll have to enable the universe repo.